# how do I get the insurgent pick-up as a personal vehicle

Tags: grand-theft-auto-online

I play GTA online on PC.

The insurgent pick-up is normally a Pegasus vehicle. This means that unlike regular personal vehicles it can't be used on missions.

However I have seen someone with one on a mission. Was he cheating or is there a way to get the insurgent pick up as a personal vehicle legitimately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it's possible.

To turn the insurgent pick-up into a personal vehicle it needs to be upgraded to the insurgent pick up custom. The upgrade cost 202500

Unfortunately this cannot be done at a regular mod shop. Instead a "vehicle workshop" is needed. I used the one in the avenger but according to GTA wikia you can also used the one in the mobile operations laboratory (though someone edited my post claiming the opposite). Unfortunately it seems you can't use a friends workshop, only your own.

Answer (score 1):

As for upgrading the Insurgent Pick up into Insurgent Pick up Custom you can also modify it at the Mobile Operation Center (MOC) with a Vehicle Workshop purchased. But in order to purchase the MOC you need to own a Bunker. Pretty much the same goes for the Avenger; I believe you need to own a Research Facility and you also need to equip the Avenger with a Vehicle Workshop. I guess it all comes down to the price, whether you will find a Bunker cheaper than the Facility or vice-versa. To be honest it is best to wait for sales in the game. They often offer great deals.

Comment: The mobile operations centre is considerably cheaper than the avenger and a bunker is cheaper than a facility. So if your only goal is to get the insurgent pick-up custom then a bunker seems to be the way to go.